# Violate No Adjacent Flower Rule

Tags: algorithm

You have a long flowerbed in which some of the plots are planted, and some are not. However, flowers cannot be planted in adjacent plots.
Given an integer array flowerbed containing 0's and 1's, where 0 means empty and 1 means not empty, and an integer n, return true if n new flowers can be planted in the flowerbed without violating the no-adjacent-flowers rule and false otherwise.

Example 1:
Input: flowerbed = [1,0,0,0,1], n = 1
Output: true
Example 2:
Input: flowerbed = [1,0,0,0,1], n = 2
Output: false

Does anyone know why in this case the output 1 is true?
Input:
[0,0,1,0,0]
1
Output:
false
Expected:
true

Comment: It seems you are asking us to do your homework. We don't do that here. If you give it a try and have a specific question, that is fine. Come back when you tried yourself and have a problem with your code. Don't forget to post the code you have by then.

Comment: Why did you tag this as `dsa`?  The `dsa` tag is for `Digital Signature Algorithm`.

Comment: Text which is copied from another source (here, some kind of assignment, I would guess) should have its source cited: https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing. Otherwise, you should rephrase the problem in your own words, instead of including the exact quote. Formulating your own description of the problem also can often help in understanding it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return if n (amount of) new flowers can be planted in the flowerbed without violating the no-adjacent-flowers rule.

so its not n HAS to be Max amount possible to be planted.
its if N is less than or equal to max planted.